# MERGE statement - Don't update OR insert when a condition is met between source and target

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
MERGE StudentTable as target 
USING MemberTable as source
ON target.StudentGUID = source.MemberGUID
WHEN MATCHED
  THEN UPDATE
    SET target.CourseId = source.CourseId,
        target.HomeCityId = ISNULL(source.HomeLocation,-1),
        target.ClassID = source.ClassIDNum,
        target.UpdatedOn = GETUTCDATE(),
        target.UpdatedBy = 'System'
WHEN NOT MATCHED
  THEN INSERT (StudentGUID, CourseId, HomeCityId,ClassID, CreatedOn, CreatedBy)
      VALUES (source.MemberGUID, source.CourseId, ISNULL(source.HomeLocation,-1), source.ClassIDNum, (GETUTCDATE()), 'System');
```

I need to modify the above MERGE statement such that the UPDATE and INSERT are NOT run when `target.StudentGUID = source.MemberGUID AND TRY_CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, HomeCityId) IS NULL AND [ClassID] <> 2`

I tried adding that condition in the `ON` clause, but that means that if the target's record won't get updated, but it WILL get inserted. I want it to NOT update or insert when the condition is met.

NOTE: StudentTable cannot have duplicate `StudentGUID` records.

Comment: Personally, I suggest using an "upsert" instead

Comment: That doesn't make sense: if you don't have a match (for the `insert` side) how can you compare them? Sounds like you just want `WHEN MATCHED AND (TRY_CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, HomeCityId) IS NOT NULL OR [ClassID] = 2)`. Alternatively, assuming these conditions are on a single table, you can merge through a view, for example `MERGE ... USING (SELECT ... WHERE ...) AS source...`

Comment: @Charlieface Ok, then will your `WHEN MATCHED` clause prevent INSERT if `(TRY_CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, HomeCityId) IS NULL AND [ClassID] <> 2)`?

Comment: @Charlieface Also, why did you change it to `OR ClassID =2` instead of AND?

Comment: No it won't, for that you need to use a derived table/view as I mentioned. But it's unclear what comes from what table: how does it make sense `TRY_CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, target.HomeCityId)` if there is no match in that table? The condition is reversed because you appear to want `WHEN MATCHED` when the condition is true, not false.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your script like this, then it will work:

```
MERGE StudentTable as target 
USING MemberTable as source
ON target.StudentGUID = source.MemberGUID
WHEN MATCHED AND
            target.CourseId     <> source.CourseId
        OR  target.HomeCityId   <> ISNULL(source.HomeLocation,-1)
        OR  target.ClassID      <> source.ClassIDNum
        OR  target.UpdatedOn    <> GETUTCDATE()
        OR  target.UpdatedBy    <> 'System'
  THEN UPDATE
    SET target.CourseId     = source.CourseId,
        target.HomeCityId   = ISNULL(source.HomeLocation,-1),
        target.ClassID      = source.ClassIDNum,
        target.UpdatedOn    = GETUTCDATE(),
        target.UpdatedBy    = 'System'
WHEN NOT MATCHED
  THEN INSERT (StudentGUID, CourseId, HomeCityId,ClassID, CreatedOn, CreatedBy)
      VALUES (source.MemberGUID, source.CourseId, ISNULL(source.HomeLocation,-1), source.ClassIDNum, (GETUTCDATE()), 'System');
```